# How to start an application with pywinauto if it does not exist?

Tags: python, pywinauto

I have tried to use the following code to connect to an existing application using `pywinauto`, and to start it if it is not running yet:

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
from pywinauto import Desktop
from pywinauto.timings import TimeoutError
from pywinauto.findbestmatch import MatchError

path = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Path\To\app.exe"    

try:
    dialog = Desktop(backend="uia")["MyProgram"]
except TimeoutError:
    dialog = Application(backend='uia').start(path, timeout=300)
```

However I still get an error

```
...
pywinauto.timings.TimeoutError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
....
pywinauto.findbestmatch.MatchError: Could not find 'MyProgram' in ...
```

So how do I catch the exception? I tried `TimeoutError` and `MatchError`, but I get the exception anyway. Or maybe is there a better way to check if an application is running?

Just figured out I do not get any error, even the application is NOT running. Now I am totally confused. The line

```
dialog = Desktop(backend="uia")["MyProgram"]
```

does not fail if the application is NOT running. And it returns a `pywinauto.application.WindowSpecification` object.

I *guess* I have to check `dialog.exists`. I failed to find documentation on the `pywinauto.Desktop` class...